# webrtc video call working on local network but on internet remote video is not loading

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

Found Many articles on googling but not found any helpful 
i am using asp.net MVC as signaling server 
Please review the code [here](https://testsite.pameric.com/code.txt)
and demo [here](https://testsite.pameric.com)
The Solution is working fine on local network but when i try on internet with two different internet connections the remote video is not loading 
Please Help me i am stuck in this problem 
**Thanks**